# Remove tags from the kses filter

Tags: filters, tags, html, wp-kses

I know one can modify the kses filter to add new allowed tags to it, but is there a way to remove some of them? I can't find how. I need to disallow DIV tags.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why disallow div tags??

Comment: I needed this for a client who insisted on pasting content from sites with malformed HTML in the editor, thus screwing the site design as a result. At the end, enabling the use_balanceTags option was enough.

Comment: Wasn't that fixed with TinyMCE 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allowed tags are stored in `$allowedposttags` (located in `/wp-includes/kses.php`) as an array. For each element it looks something like this:

```
$allowedposttags = array(
  'div' => array(
    'align' => true,
    'dir' => true,
    'lang' => true,
    'xml:lang' => true,
  )
);
```

You can remove a single element of an array via [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

```
unset($allowedposttags['div']);
```